# XUnit: Breakpoints in methods refrenced by [MemberData] are not working

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, xunit

Using .net core 3.1, I added an xunit project to a solution with the following test class:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xunit;

namespace BP
{
    public class BreakPointFails
    {
        public static IEnumerable<object[]> GetData
        {
            get
            { // <------- VS never hits this breakpoint
                return new List<object[]>
                {
                    new object[] { "name", "Bill" },
                    new object[] { "name", "Paul" },
                    new object[] { "name", "Steve" }

                };
            }
        }
        [Theory]
        [MemberData("GetData")]
        public void ExtractScopeStringTest(string name, string lastName)
        {
            Assert.True(name != lastName);
        }
    }
}
```

If I mark a breakpoint at line with the comment "<------- VS never hits this breakpoint", VS debugger never stops at that line. Breakpoints anywhere else worke fine, but the in the methods pointed by [MemberData] attribute.

I am **emphesising** that the debug seup is fine and breakpoints anywhere in the test methods work perfect except methods pointed by [MemberData].

Why is that?

**Update 1:**
Line with the breakpoint comment in the code above is juts to indicate a VS breakpoint to be added. The Markdown doesn't allow me to show a breakpoint red dot in the question.

Comment: Why do you need to set breakpoints at line with the comment ? Visual Studio Xunit console runner creates AppDomain with test data for 'MemberData', so the data will be saved in memory after build.

Comment: @XingyuZhao, Line with the breakpoint comment in the code above is juts to indicate a VS breakpoint to be added. The Markdown doesn't allow me to show a breakpoint red dot in the question.

Comment: Could you provide more details about 'Markdown'? I can see my breakpoint dot in my Visual Studio.

Comment: @XingyuZhao, any breakpoint insie the meber that MemberData is pointing won't work. In my example, any breakpoint inside GetData->Get won't work.